# Printing variable after fetching data from API gives empty and after that filled value is printed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

Say I fetched an API in React and set its value in datalists

```
const [dataLists, setdataLists] = useState([])

const fetchAPI = () => {
        axios.get(`/api/fetchDetails/fetchData/${comp_id}`).then((data) => {

            setdataLists(data.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);

        })
    }

useEffect(() => {
        fetchAPI()
    }, [])

console.log(dataLists) # This prints first empty array and then the value is printed though I have 
                         called after data has been set.
```

I want to print the data not empty array after fetchAPI function has been called and value is set. As because of empty array any operation I perform using dataLists it gives error as not defined because at start it gets empty array and after that only gets value.

If any more information is needed please do let me know.

Comment: Axios work asynchronously, set some default value of dataset and check before use the dataset is set something like this if(dataset.length!=0)

Comment: `useEffect` is called only after a component is mounted. So your first `console.log` will always print the initial state you pass to `useState`.

Comment: @NareshTeli Sorry I'm not sure that I follow what you are saying. Could you please be more distinct. What can be set as default value? What do you purpose?

Comment: @ShriharshaKL So what do you purpose that needs to be done. As I have till now worked like this only, so I'm a bit lost

Comment: As the code is async, it will first trigger the get function, and the execute the console.log statement, if you want it to print, add the console.log inside the axios.get().then((data)=>{console.log(data.data))}

Comment: @SangamBasnet One way to handle such situations is by using a loading state in the component. You can set `loading: true` before you call the API and reset it after the API finishes. As for other logic in the component, you can always check the loading flag before you perform any operations.

Comment: @SangamBasnet: Have answered this question and provided the best possible structure that you should always follow when dealing with async - code... :) Hope that will help. Do Vote and Accept if this helps :)

Comment: @SangamBasnet  [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is clear the you are doing `console.log(dataLists)` within the Component outside of the `useEffect()`.

Note that `useEffect()` is called after the component's `JSX` is rendered. So, as the component - which is essentially a function - when it runs it passes this line of  code `console.log(dataLists)` and since you have `dataLists`state  variable set to an `empty array` initially it outputs an empty array.

```
const [dataLists, setdataLists] = useState([]);
```

So, you must create a good structure of your code. Add a `loading` state, and and `error` state for instance, and handle JSX accordingly.

**USING THE FOLLOWING STRUCTURE WILL BE HELPFUL:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const url = "https://api.github.com/users/emmeiwhite";

// Conditional Renders
const FetchingAndShowing = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          setLoading(false);
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Error: Could not fetch the data");
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setUser({ ...user, ...data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(true);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <h3>Loading ...</h3>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <h3>Error in the API call itself ...</h3>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Name: {user.login}</h1>
        <img src={user.avatar_url} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default FetchingAndShowing;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and yes this is the method that I use to call api using loading and error. And I'm able to resolve my query to some extent using if else method as suggested by @zahra zamani. Bu when I set if dataList.length > 0 and do console.log, it is re-rendered twice and when I perform setState inside the if condition it gives me error: too many redirects. And also in useEffect I'm using empty [], so it should have rendered once. Could you help me on how it can be done. Have you understood what I'm trying to say or should I edit the question itself.

Comment: I would love to help :) But I need to check the issue myself. Do one think create a codesandbox project. Add your components.... Use my above API for testing and share the link with me... :-) I will help, Don't worry... i love ReactJS

Comment: @SangamBasnet : Dear Friend ! I would let u know that unless I know what is happening in you code, I can't tell what the error is. Second is Asynchronous world is a different world - where we don't know when we'll have the data available.. U'll have your query resolved if you send me the codesandbox link :) I promise

Comment: Sorry Imran to keep you waiting.....thank you so much for your support. I really appreciate it. :)

Here's the link for codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/black-brook-8wfbr?file=/src/App.js

I have commented in which line I'm facing the issue. If you need any further information do let me know. :)

Comment: Bro did you come up with the solution or do you have any suggestion for me. Please do let me know.

Comment: Dear Friend :) As I have mentioned above ! I need to have your code. I will see how you have implemented your component and accordingly provide you the solution :) Please create a codesandbox project and share the link with me :)

Comment: I have shared my sample codesandbox link......here is the link once again :  codesandbox.io/s/black-brook-8wfbr?file=/src/App.js

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Oh Boy!!!  I didn't saw it earlier !!! Let me check it now

Comment: Let's discuss in the chatroom !!! So that I can get responses from you to get clarity of things :)

Comment: Can't create it now.  I saw your message **  //In my code when I try to setDataSet inside if condition it
  //gives me error: too many re-directs.**. My question is are you trying to use setDataset() within your JSX ?

Comment: Dear Friend, Please add your JSX inside return as well. So that I'll see what is going on... See using setDataset() inside the JSX means a new render every time... That's why you getting this message..

Comment: We don't need if/else etc. inside component at all ! Just tell me what you are trying to achieve :) What is you requirement and what are you trying to do ultimately within JSX

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-issue-hkf04 :) What we ultimately want to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to set value after it is inside the if...else statement and after that I use that variable to pass data to another element inside JSX

Comment: Sorry i cannot come to chat as my reputation is very low

Comment: I gave you reputation of 10 :) Let me try from myside ! I think you should have 20 :) Anyways ! Can you add you JSX part also :) Things are not yet clear

Comment: Check this Mate ! Here I am rendering my data once it is available inside JSX ? https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-issue-hkf04?file=/src/App.js . The same way I want to know what do you want display within JSX :) Hope my question is clear ?

Comment: I'm so sorry but I cannot share exact code as it is not allowed for me to share...but element is rendered with data only when there is click of button and the value sets and displays the actual data but when it is not clicked I want to set the value by default. But cannot set value as it is rendered twice and react throws error. So only solution I have is to the way I have been doing. If you have any other way to do out of the JSX element please let me know..Thank you so much for your enthusiasm

Answer (score 0):

```
 const fetchAPI =async () => {
     await   axios.get(`/api/fetchDetails/fetchData/${comp_id}`).then((data) => {

            setdataLists(data.data);
            console.log(data.data); #They both will work
            console.log(dataLists); #They both will work
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);

        })
    }
```

And apply the condition before print dataLists for example:

```
{dataLists &&  dataLists.length !=0 ? ///The codes you want to use :[]}
```

Comment: so The only thing that comes to my mind is to use the condition..

Comment: Your opinion is totally valid but since it renders twice when I try to set its value to another variable or play with setState it gives me error: Too many re-Renders.

Comment: @zahrazamani : Hi there ! Hope you are doing good ! Just for you information and learning purpose... How would async-await solve this problem that OP has :) ! It's the better code structure that OP needs to solve the problem... Because outside async-function console.log() will always be invoked before useEffec() ... Fee AmaanilLah

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @zahrazamani:  U are welcome :) And yes u have a blessed name ! Zahra :-) We have great respect for the Pure Daughter(AS) of our Beloved Prophet (AS) :)

Answer (score 0):

seeing your issue you have called the log method outside your async function thus it executes it first, and then after the data is set, it is executed again, if you want to see the data I would recommend following this approach, thus making sure the log method is only called after we get the data and not before it.

```js
const [dataLists, setdataLists] = useState([])

const fetchAPI = () => {
        axios.get(`/api/fetchDetails/fetchData/${comp_id}`).then((data) => {

            setdataLists(data.data);
            console.log(data.data); #They both will work
            console.log(dataLists); #They both will work
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);

        })
    }

useEffect(() => {
        fetchAPI()
    }, [])
```

Happy coding :)

So as per your question in the comments, to render useEffect only once we can do as follows

```js
const [location, setLocation] = useState("you route.com/somepath")

useEffect(() => {
        fetchAPI()
    }, [location])
```

the concept is that, only when we come to the page we will be rendering the useEffect() or only when we reload they will be triggered
I have used this in one of my React applications, and they are also performing well, Kindly try this out :)

Comment: Thank you for your response but the reason I wanted to print it outside is because I have to play with dataLists and since it was giving me empty and then filled value. @Zahra zamani has suggested me to use if condition but the problem here is when I try to use setValue it gives me error too many re-directs as useEffects renders twice

Comment: So do you have idea on how to render useEffects once

Comment: Yes, we can do it, i will update the answer accordingly